# How to solve this type of multi-task Bayesian optimization problem?

Tags: bayesian, optimization, gaussian-process, bayesian-optimization, multiarmed-bandit

Let us consider a collection of local Bayesian optimization tasks, each employs a Gaussian Process model to find the local optimum (i.e. global optimum of that task). The goal is to design a sequential query strategy that can find the global optimum **among all tasks** while minimizing the number of expensive evaluations. An obvious intuition is: For some tasks, the observations are always far away from the global optimum, hence should not be queried as much as the tasks that have their local optima close (or equal) to the global optimum. However, I failed to think of a way to balance exploration and exploitation in such a multitask setting. Can anyone provide some ideas on how to solve such a problem? Note that it is impossible to combine all tasks into one task since they have very different input space.

Comment: if the tasks are conditionally independent, the solution should be straightforward. did you study how to solve bayesian problems using DAGs? maybe tell us more about your problem.

Comment: @carlo Yes the tasks are conditionally indepedent. I have never solved bayesian problems using DAGs, but would like to know how this problem can be formulated as DAGs.